# HttpClient redirection result is not visible in browser

Tags: java, servlets, redirect, browser, httpclient

I am trying to redirect to "some url" using Apache Httpclient 4.3.
When the following code works, I get "200 OK" status, but nothing changs in browser.
This code is in servlet's doGet() method  and I don't want to use response.sendRedirect().

How can I see retruned web page's URL in browser?

```
 String url = "some url";
   HttpClient instance = 
         HttpClientBuilder.create().setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy()).build();

 try {
    HttpResponse response = instance.execute(new HttpGet(url));
   } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Comment: What? Why wold you expect anything to happen in the browser client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the description in your question, here's your stack:

Browser sends HTTP request to Servlet-based server. Servlet-based server uses the Apache `HttpClient` to send an HTTP request to "some url". `"some url"` responds with a redirect, 302, which the `HttpClient` follows because of its `LaxRedirectStrategy`. `"some url"` responds with some other HTTP response. The Servlet-based server completes and responds to browser client with a 200 OK.

There is **absolutely no relation** between the browser client and the Apache `HttpClient` instance you are using within your servlet.

> How can I see returned web page's URL in browser?

This doesn't make sense. If you want to see a URL in the browser, then you either need to send a request through the browser to that URL or have the **browser** follow a redirect.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Does HttpClient send redirection request two times, because in Fiddler I can see 2 responses: the first one with status 302 and the second one with 200?

Comment: @Suro HTTP works with one request, one response cycles. So, for example, the client sends one HTTP request and receives a 302 response. It sends a second HTTP request to the `Location` URL in the 302 response headers and receives a 200 response.