# Browser won't redirect with HttpClient LaxRedirectStrategy

Tags: java, http-post, httpclient, http-redirect

Am trying to make an http request post but i can't seem to figure out why my browser won't redirect even after setting redirect strategy LaxRedirectStrategy. Am i missing something here?

maven httpcomponents

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>fluent-hc</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpasyncclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

here my servlet making an request post

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String restEndpoint = "http://localhost:8080/res-auth/ep/login/post";
    if (request != null) {
        try {
            String username = request.getParameter("username");
            String password = request.getParameter("password");

            CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
                    .setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy()).build();
            JSONObject jsonUser = new JSONObject();
            jsonUser.put("email", username);
            jsonUser.put("password", password);
            jsonUser.put("rememberMe", false);
            jsonUser.put("domainHome", domainHome);
            jsonUser.put("loginHome", loginHome);
            jsonUser.put("userHome", userHome);
            jsonUser.put("callback", userHome);

            StringEntity input = new StringEntity(jsonUser.toString());
            HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(restEndpoint);
            postRequest.setEntity(input);
            postRequest.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");
            postRequest.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            postRequest.setHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

            CloseableHttpResponse restResponse = httpClient.execute(postRequest);

            System.out.println("Response code :"
                    + restResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
            try {
                final HttpEntity entity = restResponse.getEntity();
                if (entity != null) {
                    final InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                    instream.close();
                }
            } finally {
                restResponse.close();
            }

        } catch (JSONException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(HttpClientServletTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    } else {
        request.setAttribute("error", "Unknown User please try again");
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/login.xhtml").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

Here the rest api am calling

```
@POST
@Path("post")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Transactional
public Response authenticateUser(String json) throws IOException {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
    setEmail(jsonObject.get("email").toString());
    setPassword(jsonObject.get("password").toString());
    setCallback(jsonObject.get("callback").toString());
    setDomainHome(jsonObject.get("domainHome").toString());
    setRememberMe(jsonObject.getBoolean("rememberMe"));

    login(getEmail(), getPassword(), isRememberMe());
    URI uri = new URI(getCallback());
    return Response.seeOther(uri).build();
}
```

Comment: Please follow answer in link -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26343567/httpclient-redirection-result-is-not-visible-in-borwser